# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Identity: Role-based authorization -> Access Denied

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 with the new Identity framwork from .NET. The regular `Authorization` attribute works as long as no role specific role is requested.

Do I need some extending / customized policies to use roles? Below is a minimized sample of my code:

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        // Does not change anything
        // services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin"))
        {
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("danny.meier@tpcag.ch");
        if (!await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }


        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your signin method? Are you logged in with "danny.meier@tpcag.ch" or with a different user?

Comment: I'm logged in with this user. Account handling is not overridden. Behavior is like scaffolding all the stuff without changes. The IsInRoleAsync returns true as expected.

Comment: Did you log off and on, to get a fresh cookie after creating the role?

Comment: Yes I did several times. If it helps, I can provide this sample on github.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a known issue in the version of `2.1` and has been fixed in `2.2 preview-1` .

The reason is that the new method of [`AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionuiextensions.adddefaultidentity?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions_AddDefaultIdentity__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_) , which is introduced in `ASP.NET Core 2.1` , will not make `Roles` enabled by default .

To walk around it , instead of using the new `AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>()` to configure Identity , simply use the old-style api  :

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Also , if you have already signed someone in before , please do **logout first and login again**  , it will work as expected now .

---

**[Edit]**  For ASP.NET Core 3.1, invoke `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
```

And then logout and login again.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. I have the following code in an Asp.Net 2.1 project that is working:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
         .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
         //.AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```