# Role based authentication always rejects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 project with `Individual Account` authentication scaffolded in.

I've migrated across the database to add the initial tables and registered a test user account, which has been persisted correctly.

I now want to be able to control authorization across `Admin Controllers` throughout, but for some reason my Roles are always being rejected, even when applied correctly.

I added the correlation between and `ApplicationUser` (which just inherits from `IdentityUser`, no custom props) and an `IdentityRole` in `startup.cs` like so:

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And added the context of the `ApplicationUser` to my `ApplicationDbContext` like so:

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

I seeded the roles like so:

```
    public async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        var adminExists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");

        if (!adminExists)
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
        }

        var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("test@test.com");

        if(user == null)
        {
            var stew = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Email = "test@test.com"
            };

            await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
        }
    }
```

I can see in the database that the role has been created with a unique GUID, and the associated between my test account's `GUID` and the role `GUID` has been added to `AspNetUserRoles`.

In my mind, this was now complete and I should be able to just add:

`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

To block non-Admin role user accounts but I'm constantly caught with

> Access Denied. You are not allowed to view this page

Even though I only have one account, one role, and the role applied with my single account.

Is there something obvious that I've missed here? I've been tinkering for a day or so, even making a new project to test to see if I removed some boilerplate and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: For reference the email and password are correct in my code, I've replaced them in the question with filler strings to not leak anything.

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531131/asp-net-core-2-1-identity-role-based-authorization-access-denied/52546946#52546946

Comment: What happens with stew, `stew = new ApplicationUser()`? Shouldn't he be the new `user`?

Comment: @itminus Jesus wept, that's worked. Thanks for linking that across, cant believe I hadn't come across that.

Comment: @AndyG This is fixed now but to answer your question, the user authentication worked fine and I could register accounts etc, but role authorization was broken due to the known issue that itminus linked above.