# MVC Core | Access Denied | Role Issue with MVC Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using VS Code on a Mac to create a few MVC projects. These are set up on creation to use Identity Framework. I then go into the database and create an admin role and tie that to my user. When I run the project locally via Visual Studio Code and attempt to visit the controller that I have attributed with that role I am unable to get in. "Access denied... you do not have permission..".

If I open the same project in Visual Studio 2017, every thing works as it should. This has baffled me. I cannot figure out what I am missing.I have no issues pulling data from the DB to a view. Once I throw [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] onto a controller, I am redirected to Login.

I am using Core 2.2 MVC project with a MySQL database with the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql connector.

- my user is setup through the UI via "Register"
- my role and assigning that user is done through the SQL client

Comment: Have you tried logging out then assigning the role and logging back in?

Comment: No, I haven't. Also, I've run across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531131/asp-net-core-2-1-identity-role-based-authorization-access-denied

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you're setting up the authentication schemes via a default policy, for example:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var defaultRequirements = new[] {
        new DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement()
    };

    var defaultSchemes = new[] {
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
    };

    var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy(defaultRequirements, defaultSchemes);
    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultPolicy;
});
```

When you add a requirement to the `Authorize` attribute (here, a role), the default policy is ignored, and your user is not authenticated.

If that's what happen, you can add two `Authorize` attributes on your controller: one to force the authentication, and the other for the role:

```cs
[Authorize] // deny anonymous, force authentication
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] // additional roles check
public class MyController : Controller
{
}
```

Adding several `Authorize` attributes allows you to check multiple requirements (`AND` logic).